# Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent'

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am getting the following error:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent'.
```

My code is this:

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
```

Then I add a few keys to the content.

After that I have a loop with this code inside:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler, false))
{                            
    var response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = response.Content;

        bytes = responseContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
    }
    else
    {
        Response.End();
    }
 }
```

When it runs second time it gives me the above error.

Any idea why?

Thanks

Update.
As suggested changing my code to this:
I put this above the loop:

```
var client = new HttpClient(handler, false);

using (client)
{                            
   var response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
       var responseContent = response.Content;

       bytes = responseContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
   }
   else
   {
      Response.End();
   }
}
```

Now I am getting:

```
Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'
```

Comment: Do you call `Response.End();` that would prevent other stuff from running. Also `MultipartFormDataContent` is disposable, so don't dispose that. Might have to recreate that one as well.

Comment: The response will dispose the content when itself gets disposed. Don't reuse MultipartFormDataContent

Comment: @Ralf, what would I use? I am not too good with c#, just doing POC.

Comment: Actually i just tested this piece of code. Nothing inside this calls `content.Dispose()` and i was able to call it multiple times just fine. But you should also not recreate the HttpClient every time.

Comment: A "using" statement automatically disposes variables when exiting.  I think the var content = new MultipartFormDataContent(); needs to be inside the "using" statement.

Comment: I just changed my code and I am getting new error.

Comment: @jdweng. Without "using" I am still getting my original error.

Comment: Try : using (var client = new HttpClient(handler, false))

Comment: @jgweng. That is my original code.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to make a function to generate the content for you? This way you don't have to reuse the same object. Something like: private HttpContent MakeContent(var myStuff)

Comment: @Julian. Yes, I can, however, the content is pretty complex and I was hoping I can avoid repeating this process.

Comment: Don't use `using (client)` if you want to keep reusing the client. "using" will destroy the client at the end of the statement. If you also did `using (content)` then remove that using as well if you want to reuse the content.

Comment: @Charles. See my answers to jgweng